# How to implement "Personal access tokens" using Spring Boot and Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to create an application that allows an authenticated user to create [OAuth2 bearer tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-1.2) for use with APIs published by the organization. The idea is to allow the user to self generate / revoke such tokens, similar to GitHub's [Personal API tokens](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens). The user can then use the issued tokens to gain programmatic access to protected resources exposed by the same organization.

This application requires:

- A UI to authenticate a user and allow the user to generate and revoke tokens
- A server-side RESTful API that allows user authentication and token generation, revocation and storage

Ideally this application would be stateless and not require sessions, using a [SPA](http://java.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-single-page-app).

Some questions surrounding the implementation:

- Should the exposed API be the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` `/oauth/token` endpoint using the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) type? If so, is it insecure to expose the [Client Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4) to the UI? Can this be avoided?
- Should the API expose a new, dedicated endpoint which directly calls `AuthorizationServerTokenServices`? If so, how might this be achieved?
- Is there a reference implementation using Spring Boot and Spring Security OAuth2?

Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does it need to be an SPA? All you need is about one and a half pages and you can do practically everything with normal `@EnableOAuth2Client` support in the server.

Comment: @DaveSyer thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't "need" to be a SPA, but that has been the general architecture of our applications in order to keep state isolated to the UI client. Do you happen to have an example of such a use of `@EnableOAuth2Client`? If the services are collocated as described, would this require the use of a REST client that communicates over HTTP (i.e. `OAuth2RestTemplate`), or would everything remain in process using direct method invocation? Any clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: The only rest client you absolutely need in the server is the one that gets the token. Not sure what you mean by "in process". The integration tests in Spring OAuth are a good source for basic samples. I'll have a more complete sample when SpringOne is over (this week), so feel free to ping me later. IMO state concerning authentication belongs on a server of some sort, but do please look at Spring Session (now released at 1.0.0.M1) if you want to take control of that.

Comment: @DaveSyer agreed about session state needing to be on the server. Also, thanks for the pointer on Spring Session, I will certainly take a look. Regarding "in process", all these OAuth roles will be in the same process: Client, Authorization Server and Resource Server. It seems odd to have to use HTTP from the Client to the Authorization Server in such a setup.

Comment: Correct, it does seem odd, but it's only one call to the /token endpoint (or maybe you could save an HTTP request by forwarding to /authorize instead of redirecting, but it seems cleaner to redirect). To do it all client side you could use an `AccessTokenProvider` that delegated to a `TokenProvider` directly (there isn't one out of the box).

Comment: @DaveSyer in this approach do you think it makes sense to model the "user" as an OAuth "client"? Or is it more appropriate to use the "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" type?

Comment: Neither in general. A user is a user and authorization code grant is best. In your specific really narrow use case it might be that password grant is acceptable (but why do you need oauth at all if you only have one server?).

Comment: We are intending to have a 1:m relationship between the Authorization Server and Resource Servers eventually. But even with one server, giving the user the ability to issue Personal Access Tokens and leverage the Spring OAuth 2 infrastructure seems appropriate.

Comment: Then you definitely should use auth code grant. I feel like we've had this conversation before.

Comment: I don't think we have, but maybe a similar one. Auth code grant doesn't make sense to me though. Why would the user have to authorize the very app they are using to generate tokens. Anyways, I've changed my design a bit to simplify things. Now I'm using the password grant type via a command line utility with no client password. Its just a means to transition to something like auth code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not typical to require users to approve a grant for a token within the same system. Spring Oauth explicitly supports this out of the box in 2.0 (in 1.0 all you needed was a custom `UserApprovalHandler`). Auth code is just a better process, especially for the 1:m state you want to get to.